# Regex pattern for yesterday's date in format yyyymmdd

Tags: java, regex, spring, date, spring-integration

I'm working on a Spring Integration application using the file reader support.  I'm trying to use a regex filter for picking up the file desired.  The name of the file would look something like "S20110322.txt" with a new file for each day, but with the same "S" prefix.  My application will be running the day after a file is created so that it captures all the data for that day.  I'm able to use a regex filter that will match the format for any date, but I specifically need the regex pattern to only match today's date less one day since the application will automatically run daily.

In terms of Java, I could accomplish this using a SimpleDateFormat and write the Java code, but I'm just trying to see if I can accomplish it without the Java code and merely using Spring Integration's int-file:inbound-channel-adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to match yesterday's date, I can't see why you'd need a regular expression or a filter at all - you know the *exact* file that you want, don't you? Why don't you just load that specific file?

Comment: The reason I'm trying to use a regex filter is because the Spring Integration configuration is in an XML file and the regex filter is a bean property defined in that XML file.  I know full well I can accomplish this in Java, but was just trying to see if it's possible in XML just with the right regex pattern.  Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick: You're not going to be able to express the concept of "the current date" in a plain (unchanging) regex, no.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I'm not a regex expert anyways, so I'll write the Java code.  It's only going to be a couple lines at most anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the S prefix and use **DateFormat.parse()**

Note: You will have to initialize the date format to your own format first.

EDIT: I am sorry i dint read your last para about not wanting to use Datformats